# Setup From field in PowerShell outlook object

Tags: powershell, outlook

How do I add a "From" or "Send As" to this object?

```bsh
$out = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$recipient = 'Test@user.com'
$new = $out.CreateItem(0)
$new.Subject = 'Test Subject'
$new.Recipients.Add($recipient) | Out-Null
$new.Importance = 2
$new.save()
$display = $new.GetInspector
$display.Display()
```

Comment: Have you tried: `$new.SenderEmailAddress` and `$new.SenderName` or `$new.Sender`? 
If this does it let me know I'll post as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All sender related properties are set later when the message is actually sent.

If you wan to set a specific account, set the `MailItem.SendUsingAccount` property to an account object from the `Application.session.Accounts` collection.

If you want to send on behalf of a delegate Exchange mailbox, set the `MailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName` property to the name or address of that delegate mailbox.